# Creating a Heatmap of Cartisan X,Y,Z values using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

Here is what I am looking to do:

1. Import .csv file containing Cartesian Coordinates of X, Y, and Z values, as well as nominal Z values.
2. Create a 2D heatmap image of those points where X, Y are locations of known points and the Z value determines the color at that location. Specifically the deviation of the Z value from the nominal Z value for that specific X, Y point.
3. Save the image to the same directory as the .csv

I understand how to read in and save files, where I am getting hung up on is where to begin preparing the data for a heatmap.  I have been messing around using `matplotlib.pyplot`, `numpy`, and `pandas` and trying to use the `plt.contourf()` function to generate the heatmap, but I don't know enough to get it to work correctly.  Most examples and tutorials I have found use Z as some mathematical function of X, Y to keep the examples simple instead of referencing data from a file like I am trying to do.  Another issue I am facing is the data I am working with is not necessarily rectangular and does not fit nicely into a grid. They could be random X, Y points which are not evenly distributed.

Anyway here is some of the stuff I have so far (Just plots the X Y Data):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
import seaborn as sns

csv_name = 'Test.csv'

# import the .csv for heatmap
print('CSV FORMAT SHOULD BE: Point_Number, X_Coord, Y_Coord, Z_Coord, Z_Coord_Nominal, Upper_Tol, Lower_Tol')
specify_filename = input("Enter a filename for data:")
myfile = open(specify_filename)
heatmap_data = myfile.read()
myfile.close()

print('Data File Contents:')
print(heatmap_data)

# data preparation
df = pd.read_csv(specify_filename, header=None)
df.columns = ['Point_Number', 'X_Coord', 'Y_Coord', 'Z_Coord', 'Z_Coord_Nominal', 'Upper_Tol', 'Lower_Tol']

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.plot(df['X_Coord'], df['Y_Coord'], 'o')


# This is where I don't know what to do with the data to make it plot properly using plt.contourf()


# save heatmap image
print('Data File:')
print(specify_filename)
output_path = specify_filename.replace(csv_name, 'heatmap.png', 1)
print('Output File:')
print(output_path)

plt.savefig(output_path)
```

This creates a plot that looks like this:  (Note that the points are not in a rectangular grid)
[Output Image with X Y coordinates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDota.png)

Ideally the generated heatmap image will interpolate the Z value between points and look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPbJG.png)  or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeZDL.png).  I would like to use the deviation from the nominal Z values for the colors on the heatmap.

Any help or **examples** would be greatly appreciated. If I am using the wrong tools for this, I would love to know what the better alternatives are.  I barely use python so I am not extremely familiar with the nuances, but am open to any help I can get.  Thank you!

Comment: If your data isn't ordered as a grid, you can use `plt.contourf(df['X_Coord'], df['Y_Coord'], np.abs(df['Z_Coord']-df['Z_Coord_Nominal']), levels=256)`

Answer (score 0):

If your data is ordered then you can use a pcolormesh.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
theta, r = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50), np.linspace(0, 5, 50));
X_coord = r * np.cos(theta);
Y_coord = r * np.sin(theta);
Z_coord = np.sin(3*theta) * np.cos(r)
plt.pcolormesh(X_coord, Y_coord, Z_coord, shading='nearest')
```

[image: nearest]

You can smooth the image somewhat by changing the shading parameter

```py
plt.pcolormesh(X_coord, Y_coord, Z_coord, shading='gouraud')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My issue is that the Z coordinate has to be a 2D array and I am not quite sure how to make that array.  In your example you have the Z coordinate as a function of theta and r.  I understand that I need to get my z_coord as a function of x and y - I'm just not too sure how.  If you have any advice for that, I would greatly appreciate that.  My grasp of arrays isn't quite the best I suppose.

Comment: Z in the example is already a 2D array. Notice that Z also depends on theta.